# Number of license plates

Tags: combinatorics

How many license plates with 3 decimal digits followed by 3 letters do not contain
both the number 0 and the letter O?

I tried by working like since 0 is not allowed and the letter 'O' is not allowed so possible number of license plates=$9*9*9*25*25*25$ but this is not the answer.

When I checked the solution, it was like total 3 decimal digits, which contain $0$  is $10^3-9^3$
And total letters which contain $O$ is $26^3-25^3$
Hence required number of license plates=$10^3.26^3-(10^3-9^3) \times(26^3-25^3).$

I want to know where my approach failed. I understood the solution, but unless I understand where I failed, getting the solution is of no use.

Please help.

Comment: "*Does not contain both an $0$ and an $O$*"  Is different than "*Does not contain an $0$ and does not contain an $O$.*"  In both cases the license plate $012$-$MNO$ is not allowed, but the license plate $012$-$ABC$ is allowed in the first but not in the second.  Let $A$ be the set of licenseplates with a digit $0$.  Let $B$ be the set of licenseplates with a letter $O$.  You were tasked with calculating $|U\setminus(A\cap B)|=|A^c\cup B^c|$, i.e. those license plates that do not simultaneously have an $0$ and an $O$.  You accidentally calculated $|A^c\cap B^c|$ instead.

Comment: @Jmoravitz-Thank you so much. I think license plate 012-ABC is not allowed in case 1 but allowed in case 2 right?

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is missing the cases where either O or 0 can be in the licence plate. For Eg, 045FTD can be licence plate number but your approach will miss these kind of licence numbers.

Comment: Your ans is the one where the licence plates never contain 0 or O or both together